# Custom function interrupt

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

Is it possible to implement function interrupt in Qt (5.x).

For example if I have a button and want something to execute on the thread (which is running infinite loop) when this button is clicked, I could say something like this:

```
in thread...
forever
{
  if(button_is_pressed_flag)
  {
    do something...
  }
}
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Read about threads in Qt documentation. Your question doesn't make the impression you invested much effort in solving the problem by your own.

Comment: @Silicomancer Why do you think so? Isn't this one valid solution? I think you don't understand what I'm trying to achieve here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite loop should be an event loop, and then it can automatically process cross-thread slot calls without you worrying about the details.

The idiom to run code "continuously" on an event loop is the zero-duration timer.

Let's say you start with code that looks like this:

```
class MyThread : public QThread {
  bool button_is_clicked_flag = false;
  void run() override {
    forever{
      if (button_is_clicked_flag) {
        onButtonClick();
        button_is_clicked_flag = false;
      }
      doWork();
    }
  }
  void onButtonClick();
  void doWork();
public:
  using QThread::QThread;
  void setButtonClickedFlag();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ...
  MyThread t;
  t.start();
  ...
}
```

It is required for `doWork()` not to take too long - nor too short. If it took ~5ms on modern hardware, it'd be just about a right tradeoff between overhead and latency for a general-purpose application. If you need lower latency reaction in the worker thread, then `doWork()` must do less work. It probably doesn't make much sense for `doWork()` to take much less than 1ms.

And whenever `doWork()` doesn't have anything to do, e.g. if it's done with the computation it was supposed to perform, it should stop the timer that keeps it alive.

You should transform it to look as follows:

```
class MyWorker : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
  void doWork();
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) {
    if (event->timerId() == m_timer.timerId())
      doWork();
  }
public:
  explicit MyWorker(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {
    m_timer.start(0, this);
  }
  Q_SLOT void onButtonClick() {
    // Ensure we're invoked correctly
    Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == thread());
    ...
  }
}

class Window : public QWidget {
  Ui::Window ui;
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void buttonClicked();
  explicit Window(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui.button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Window::buttonClicked);
  }
};

class SafeThread : public QThread {
  Q_OBJECT
  using QThread::run; // final method
public:
  ~SafeThread() { quit(); wait(); } // we're safe to destroy - always
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ...
  MyWorker worker;
  SafeThread thread;
  Window window;
  // onButtonClick will be executed in worker->thread()
  connect(&window, &Window::buttonClicked, &worker, &MyWorker::onButtonClick);
  worker.moveToThread(&thread);
  thread.start();
  window.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The event loop that runs in `QThread::run` will continuously invoke `doWork` via the timer event handler. But whenever a cross-thread slot call needs to be made to an object living in that thread, the event loop will deliver the internal `QMetaCallEvent` representing the slot call to `QObject::event`, which will then execute the call.

Thus, when you set a breakpoint in `onButtonClick`, there will be `QObject::event` nearby on the call stack.

Comment: One question: could you explain me why are you using `QBasicTimer m_timer;`.I just can't understand why is it there with 0 timeout.

Comment: A `QBasicTimer` is simply a RAII wrapper around a timer id that you would otherwise get from `QObject::startTimer`. The `startTimer` is C-like API. Since we use C++ for a reason (not to write silly code ourselves) one should use a `QBasicTimer` instead. The zero timeout is a special value. It doesn't have anything to do with time at all. It means: "signal the timeout each time the event queue has been drained". It causes the event loop never to block to wait for new events: it continuously signals the timeout. It is like running your own `forever` loop that also drains the event queue.

Comment: Thanks! If I could I would accept your comment aswell :)

Answer (score 1):

You could start a thread and then immediately wait on a std::condition_variable, then when the button is clicked (the event being called on the main thread), notify the condition variable and the thread would awake.

However, this is a bit strange. What are you trying to do? call an asynchronous task upon a button click? In that case, perhaps it would be better just to start one from the button click event with std::packaged_task or std::async.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve here is this: this thread is reading big text file (log), parsing it and emitting signals based on what does it parse. Problem here is that I have to be able to pause that thread, stop it, allow it to parse "faster" (to sleep less between steps) etc... So condition variable is not so handy here.

Comment: You can communicate between the threads with flags, you just have to read/write to them inside a locked mutex

Comment: I know but what if I have, lets say 100 flags. It wont work so good anymore because there will always be a little delay in between.