# How to stop a qThread in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I would like to know how to properly stop a QThread. I havea infinite loop in a thread, and I would like to stop it when I do a specific action :

I have tried :

```
if (thread->isRunning()){
    worker->stop();
    thread->terminate();
}
```

the stop() method set a value to false to go out of my infinite loop.

Furthermore, I don't really understand the difference between quit(), terminate() or wait(). Can someone explain me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding `terminate`: _"Warning: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this function only if absolutely necessary."_ source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#terminate .  For the rest what in the documentation do you not understand?

Comment: Yes I know it is dangerous, that's why I would like to know how stop the thread properly.

Comment: In the documentation, it seems that both methods (with exit() too), tell the thread loop to exit. I don't really see the difference

Comment: use an `std::atomic<bool>` or `std::atomic_bool` variable.  Set it in your _"specific action"_ and test it in your thread proc and exit cleanly.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40976679/1329652) that details how to transform the infinite loop you have to a loop that interoperates with the event system and queued slots and is thus more flexible and easier to use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A proper answer depends on how you actually use `QThread` and how you've implemented `stop()`.

An intended use case in Qt assumes following model:

- You create an object that will do some useful work in response to Signals
- You create a `QThread` and move your object to this thread
- When you send a signal to your object, it's processed in `QThread` you've created

Now you need to understand some internals of how this is actually implemented. There are several "models" of signals in Qt and in some cases when you "send a signal" you effectively simply call a "slot" function. That's a "direct" slot connection and in this case `slot()` will be executed in *caller thread*, one that raised a signal. So in order to communicate with another thread, Qt allows another kind of signals, **queued connections**. Instead of calling a `slot()`, caller *leaves a message* to object that owns this slot. A thread associated with this object will read this message (at some time later) & perform execution of `slot()` itself.

Now you can understand what's happening when you create and execute `QThread`. A newly created thread will execute `QThread::run()` that, by default, will execute `QThread::exec()` which is nothing, but an infinite loop that looks for messages for objects associated with thread and transfers them to slots of these objects. Calling `QThread::quit()` *posts a termination message* to this queue. When `QThread::exec()` will read it, it will stop further processing of events, exit infinite loop and gently terminate the thread.

Now, as you may guess, in order to *receive termination message*, two conditions must be met:

- You should be running `QThread::exec()`
- You should exit from slot that is currently running

The first one is typically violated when people subclass from `QThread` and override `QThread::run` with their own code. In most cases this is a wrong usage, but it's still very widely taught and used. In your case it seems that you're violating the second requirement: your code runs infinite loop and therefore `QThread::exec()` simply doesn't get a control and don't have any chance to check that it needs to exit. Drop that infinite loop of yours to recycle bin, `QThread::exec()` is already running such loop for you. Think how to re-write your code so it *does not* running infinite loops, it's always possible. Think about your program in terms of "messages-to-thread" concept. If you're checking something periodically, create a `QTimer` that will send messages to your object and implement a check in your slot. If you processing some large amount of data, split this data to smaller chunks and write your object so it will process *one chunk at a time* in response to some message. E.g. if you are processing image line-by-line, make a slot `processLine(int line)` and send a sequence of signals "0, 1, 2... height-1" to that slot. Note that you will also have to explicitly call `QThread::quit()` once done processing because event loop is infinite, it doesn't "know" when you processed all the lines of your image. Also consider using `QtConcurrent` for computationally-intensive tasks instead of `QThread`.

Now, the `QThread::terminate()` does stop a thread in a very different manner. It simply asks OS to kill your thread. And OS will simply abruptly stop your thread at arbitrary position in the code. Thread stack memory will be free'd, but any memory this stack *pointed to* won't. If a thread was owning some resource (such as file or mutex), it won't ever release it. An operation that involve writing data to memory can be stopped in the middle and leave memory block (e.g. object) incompletely filled and in invalid state. As you might guess from this description, you should never, ever call `::terminate()` except for very rare cases where keeping running of thread is worse than getting memory & resource leaks.

`QThread::wait()` is just a convenience function that waits until `QThread` ceases to execute. It will work both with `exit()` and `terminate()`.

You can also implement a threading system of your own subclassed from `QThread` and implement your own thread termination procedure. All you need to exit a thread is, essentially, just to return from `QThread::run()` when it becomes necessary and you can't use neither `exit()` nor `terminate()` for that purpose. Create your own synchronization primitive and use it to signal your code to return. But in most cases it's not a good idea, keep in mind that (unless you work with `QEventLoop` by yourself), Qt signal and slots won't be working properly in that case.

Comment: _"In most cases this is a wrong usage"_ <--- that's some hot take